# How to map Apple wireless keyboard keys in Android 10

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I'm having trouble using the Return/Enter key on the Apple wireless keyboard (model A1314) while connected via Bluetooth on Android 10 (device: Google Pixel 3).

Specifically, I'd like to use the Fn+Return keystroke to act as the standard Enter key, but it doesn't work --at least not in the Messages app.

Is there a way to map the Return key so that it acts like Enter?

Comment: What do you think the difference is between `Return` and `Enter`? AFAIK these are synonyms, or did I miss something fabulous and new?

Comment: @zx485, they are different in the Apple universe.  The "Enter" label is added to the "Return" key to make non-Mac users feel at home, and the Fn+Return keystroke is supposed to mimic the standard Enter key used elsewhere in computing.